# What models can we compare using deviance?

Tags: likelihood, deviance

I have one response variable and 6 cofactors: *a, b, c, x, y, z*. 
Can I compare a model ~*x, y, z* against model ~*x, b, c* or model *~x,z* using the deviance? 
Why? Why not?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What are x, y, z, b, and c?

Comment: @MatthewDrury, those are the covariables. Sorry it was not clear.
Would you please remove/help me remove the "on hold" status?

Comment: @Luis, the fact that trying to answer this question requires "wild guess[es]" implies that this is too unclear to really be answerable. I'm voting to leave closed. If you can provide more information about your situation, your data, your models, & your goals, this might be viably answerable. Your question about how to compare non-nested models seems reasonable, but I suspect it's a duplicate.

Comment: @gung, I edited the question, is it now that unclear? I want to know if I can   run a test on the deviances to compare the fit of 2 non-nested models. 
I have a dataset with hormonal levels and biomarkers values for people that were tested for diabetes; I´m running logistic regressions and trying to compare the models I got that attempt to predict the presence of the disease based on those biomarkers.

Comment: Your comment is considerably clearer than your question. Why don't you add that information (& more) to your question? Please include more information about your situation, your data, your models, & your goals. What do you mean by "compare"? What would your comparison do for you?

Answer (score 7):

I will make a wild guess that you are fitting generalized linear models and x, y, z, b and c represent different factors or covariates that you might include in the linear model.

The answer is that, no, you can't compare the model ~x+y+z with the model ~x+b+c. Differences in deviances represent likelihood ratio tests, and likelihood ratio tests can only be used to compare nested models. In other words, one model needs to be a subset of the other. The two models you mention are not comparable because neither is a subset of the other.

Comment: If the degrees of freedom of the two models are the same (as they might be, particularly if none are factors) then in the sense that deviance corresponds to likelihood, you can compare the raw values of deviance and say that the fit of one model is better (in that sense of higher likelihood) than the other, in the same way one might compare SSE for two regression models with the same number of coefficients and say that one has a smaller SSE. You can't test if one is better than the other that way, though, and it would be appropriate to question whether it meant anything or was simply noise.

Comment: @Glen_b, so what would be a fair way to make a comparison between these models?

Comment: There is some testing theory (such as that of Vuong, 1989), but it's not clear a test actually solves your problem -- because you don't explain what you're trying to get from this. What do you need from the model -- what's it for, and what are you trying to achieve when comparing models?